# Gtk.MessageDialog window parameter problems

Tags: python, quickly, gtk3

I'm in a deeply nested class (which inherits from `Gtk.Box`) and I need to get a reference to the GtkWindow I'm in to pass to a call to Gtk.MessageDialog() yet I cant seem to find a reference to it.

I have tried `self.props.window` as well as `self.get_parent_window()` with no avail.

Everything I try to do leads to the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected Gtk.Window, but got GObjectMeta
```

Code snippet is as follows:

```
def on_tb_del_clicked(self,widget):
    question = _("Are you sure you want to do this?")
    win = self.get_parent_window() 
    dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(win,0,Gtk.MessageType.QUESTION,
                                   Gtk.ButtonsType.YES_NO,question) # <<Exception 
    response = dialog.run()
```

Please help :)

Comment: Furthermore i can appreciate the workaround is to simply pass my Top level class reference of my GtkWindow down the chain myself manually but i was hoping there was a nicer API property that i was missing as i would have thought all widgets would benefit from knowing a reference to their top level window??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [`widget.get_toplevel()`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--get-toplevel) method to find the parent window.

Comment: @William Culver so how did you workaround this problem ?